# How does one use the semantic-ui-react Label OnRemove handler /removeIcon property?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I noticed that the semantic-ui-react Label has an OnRemove handler as well as a removeIcon property. I am wondering how this is supposed to be used with other controls, as it does not seem to be well documented. For example, how would I make use of this with an Input or Form.Input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an usage example:**

```
onRemove = (event, data) => {
    console.log("onRemove event");
}

render() {
    return (
        <Label color='teal' content='Label content' removeIcon='delete' 
           onRemove={this.onRemove} />
    );
}
```

[image]